# Is it possible to do a Git Pull from Amazon Web Services?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm relatively new to Git and AWS.

I have a Drupal installation which I pushed up to AWS using 'eb start'.  I'm in an environment where designers will be using FTP to drop edits (css mostly, some tpl) on the AWS (remote) while I am working local.

Should I just be doing a fetch / merge every time I am ready to 'git aws.push' my changes to the AWS instance? Is it possible to pull from AWS???

If it isn't possible to pull from AWS then AWS isn't functional as a working environment and I'll have to use a different web host.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend putting the files that your customers drop in the git repository in the Elastic Beanstalk instance where you are running your application.  An Elastic Beanstalk instance is not always in a consistent state per se. For example, let's say you have autoscale enabled, another exact copy of your instance would be created if there's a lot of load.  What happens when say a developer decides to push files to your Elastic Beanstalk stack... the changes get pushed to just one of the instances, and when your load is not high enough that instance terminated, and you lose your changes.

Haven't said that you can host your git repository in say github, bitbucket or a cloud git repository. You can have developers pull from/push to that repository rather than the repository in the Elastic Beanstalk instance. Then to deploy the code you just run `git pull origin <your-branch>` and then `git aws.push`

Another option is to have your developers drop the files in S3 and you personally take care of merging files. If you are concerned about redundancy S3 has its own redundancy mechanism.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk is *not* a Git repository. It is a *deployment-only* endpoint.

You develop your code using Git, and a standard Git repository (e.g., GitHub, BitBucket, your own). Whenever you're ready to deploy, you push to the Elastic Beanstalk *remote* instead of your development *remote*.

> *Oddible says:* I have a Drupal installation which I pushed up to AWS using 'eb start'. I'm in an environment where designers will be using FTP to drop edits (css mostly, some tpl) on the AWS (remote) while I am working local.

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how Elastic Beanstalk works. This would be done at your application's level, not at the infrastructure level.

> *Rico says:* I don't recommend putting the files that your customers drop in the git repository in the Elastic Beanstalk instance where you are running your application.

Because there *isn't* one. Elastic Beanstalk's deployment mechanism *speaks* the Git interface for accepting deployments, but is not a real Git repository on the back end.

> *Rico says:* Another option is to have your developers drop the files in S3 and you personally take care of merging files. If you are concerned about redundancy S3 has its own redundancy mechanism.

This.

Personally, I have people contribute via GitHub, but that's what makes the most sense for my app's contribution workflow.

Comment: > This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how Elastic Beanstalk works. This would be done at your application's level, not at the infrastructure level. <
Not really sure what you mean by this, eb start is creating the infrastructure (instance, interface, rds, application, etc) and pushing the selected git commit to the application.  My question was whether it was reasonable to have designers working directly on the AWS application. Sadly they don't have local installations.  Thanks for your post, basically saying I have to have a dev server for them to post/test to that is a true git repo.

Comment: @Oddible: "My question was whether it was reasonable to have designers working directly on the AWS application." Right. That's what I meant when I said that this portion ("[…] to drop edits (css mostly, some tpl)") needs to happen at your application's level.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to git pull it. Just go to your Beanstalk control panel, select the application, and on the Action button select "Load Configuration". Then selelect "Application Versions" on the left. You'll see the get pulls that that beanstalk app did. You can then download that application as a zip.